# server benchmarking with apache benchmark

Tags: performance-tuning, apache-2.2, stress-testing, ab

We are testing one of our production server with ab and what we found is

```
apr_socket_recv: Connection timed out (110)
Total of 176 requests completed
```

after some time above output.That means the server could not handled 200 requests?
Or what exactly could be the problem and how to reach to the bottom of it?